# UIButton backgroundImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uikit, uibutton, uiimage

I have a `UIButton` with a specified width of 200. Its `autoresizingMask` property is set to `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth`. A `UIImage` is applied to this button's `backgroundImage` property. This `UIimage` is defined as follows:

```
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonimage.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10 topCapHeight:0]
```

`buttonimage.png` has a width of 400px (2x width of button, because of retina resolution) and represents a rounded rectangle. In portrait mode, everything is fine. As soon as the user rotates the device and the iPhone enters landscape mode, the `UIButton` is stretched. Due to this behaviour, the left rounded border of the image stays the same (`stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:`) but the right corners are also stretched. Is there any property I forgot to set that ensures only one specified pixel (e.g. the tenth one) is stretched and anything else retains it dimensions?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: If I use a smaller image, that is already stretched in portrait mode, both borders seem to be expanded.

**Solved!**
If your image is called "myImage.png" and it is the retina version, just call it "myImage@2x.png"

Comment: You should provide the `buttonimage.png` in non retina size and a second version in retina size name `buttonimage@2x.png`. Maybe this solves your problem.

Comment: This behaviour occurs both on a non-retina and a retina-resolution-supporting device. And if I understand this correctly, the buttonimage@2x.png file is the only one accessed by devices with retina-resolution so this would make no difference. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: right. I've tried a simple example and there is a funny effect, when I set the left cap to a small amount like 3px it smears this part along the whole button and the rest is correctly painted aligned to the right side. Looks the same for landscape. My button image is 50x50, when I set the left cap to 21px which is exactly after the round corners it does look good even in landscape. Maybe some try and error will do?

Comment: I now added a non-retina version of my button and suddenly it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any property I forgot to set
>   that ensures only one specified pixel
>   (e.g. the tenth one) is stretched and
>   anything else retains it dimensions?

Not really, but given the size of your images, you should re-read the [leftCapWidth](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html) property.

The way stretchable images work is: you provide the left cap, the next pixel is stretched, and the right side of the image with `width = (total width - left cap + 1)` stays the same. Given that you are setting left cap to 10, and the original image is 400, you are telling iOS that the right non stretchable right side of your image is `400-10-1=389px`. The same thing applies vertically.  Check if you are using @2x images on a normal device without a @2x on its name, or if the 2x versions don't have exactly twice the pixels, or there is an uppercase/lowercase difference. You can find this out nslogging the size of the image loaded.

I don't know why the right side of your image is stretched. Given that you have `height=0`, the whole image can be stretched vertically if the button height changes, but it's unlikely that this causes a distortion of only the right side.

Comment: I now added a non-retina version of my button and suddenly it worked. You guided me to the right path.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with your code as far as I can tell, that should be causing the right side of the image to be cropped. Below is the exact code I use, which I know works, to produce the same effect you're looking for.

```
UIButton *button=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 245, 51)];
button.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
[button setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"userbubble.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:40 topCapHeight:0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

My guess is that the problem is coming from the png you're using, or possibly from the Compress PNG Files setting in your project. Also, since the image you are using is so big, try putting the left cap out further, say 40 or 50 pixels in.

Comment: This is the exact code I use. I just tried it with a smaller image and strangely enough, both borders are slightly stretched. (Both in landscape and portrait mode)

Comment: Try giving yourself a larger left cap (say 50% of the image), and if things still look weird check the Compress PNG Files setting under your app target & project settings. Turn it off and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Tried both options. Still no difference. I uploaded my buttonimage. Maybe you spot any difference between your userbubble.png and my image. (grin)

Comment: I added your button to my xcode project, and it worked perfectly fine, so the problem must be coming from somewhere else. `UIButton *button=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 91, 86)];
[button setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonImage.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:40 topCapHeight:0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

Comment: Did you use only the @2x button? Weird. As I added above, I now use a non-retina and a @2x version of my button and it works. I appreciate your effort. Thank you very much!

Comment: If you use `UIButton *button=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 91, 43)];` and the height of the image file is double the size of the frame, you apparently need a non-retina version too. Hmm...